# Will Timer/blob triggers in azure always use host resources even though it's not executing?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger, azure-billing

Once deployed the Trigger functions are long running tasks that trigger on certain events is what I believe to be true.

To be precise, consider a scenario where I have deployed a Blob trigger which checks for file upload to blob storage.

After executing the trigger function. does my application still uses Host resources since it always listens to the blob storage for changes.

Is it like a websocket? Or the blob itself calls the function? Or what is it?

Is it the same with the timer trigger?

Just wanted to know if the resources are being used even after the triggers are already been executed.

Comment: Is this is a more "theoretical" question on whether resources are being consumed somewhere, or are you simply asking whether you're going to be billed simply for having a function with a `timer trigger` or a `blob trigger`?

Comment: Yes @akseli it's from a theoretical perspective as to how it operates exactly in a high level view, Will it be active and always be listening like a socket connection? or some other event starts the process? how is it?

Comment: No. AFAIK, trigger is not listening always same as WebSocket. It doesn't continuously consume resources while waiting for an event, it only runs when an actual trigger event happens.

Comment: Also why do we have to restart the application if we want reflect the changes in `local.settings.json` in our function?, if we have to restart an application doesn't it mean that its always running?
P.S I'm new to this please help me out here.

Comment: `local.settings.json` is used only when you are running the function locally. when you are deploying the function to Azure, default Variables will be defined in `Environment variables`. if you have created any custom variable then you need to define it in `Environment variables` after deploying to Azure

Comment: Function is Always running after deployment but you will be charged based on the service plan you have selected. if you have selected `consumption` you will charged only when you trigger is executed and if you are selecting `Premium` or `App service plans`, then you will be charges based on the plan you have selected. charges will be mentioned when selcting the plans. you can also check here using [calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/)

Comment: So in a deployed function do i need to restart the application if i change the environment variable? 

for example i am currently using octopus variables to configure my application's environment variables.

Comment: No, AFAIK usually, you don't need to restart, it automatically takes effect after adding the variable. but if its not working you can restart the function app.

Answer (score 0):

> **Will Timer/blob triggers in azure always use host resources even though it's not executing?**

Azure Function has **Consumption** and **Premium** service plans,
Also, The App service plan can be used for azure function too.

[image]

**Consumption Plan:** It charges based on the times your function has executed or ran; it will be shown as the `Y1` plan name. For reference, you can check this Pricing [calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/) for functions, also mentioned in the document for consumption plan.

> The first 400,000 GB/s of execution and 1,000,000 executions are free.

**Premium Plan:** This plan has multiple options for instances, vCore, storage size. Each has different pricing; you can check it in Pricing calculator too.

Storage account is created with every function app and that will be charged differently based on usage. You can check the pricing for the storage account in the calculator.
For reference, check this [Document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/).

> Just wanted to know if the resources are being used even after the triggers are already been executed.

No, the trigger function is not "always listening" in the same way that a WebSocket is. Instead, it's an event-driven function. It doesn't continuously consume resources while waiting for an event; it only runs when there is an actual trigger event.

I have created a timer trigger and blob trigger function in my Azure function. This is the accumulated cost for 20 runs and 5 runs for Azure storage, as shown below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]